# Debian 9 failover between WAN and cellular module

Tags: debian, mobile, failover

I'm trying to configure a debian 9 device to have cellular failover in case WAN fails (or vice versa). I tried doing this with `ifenslave`, the failover works in general but it doesn't switch gateways. It keeps the primary one.

Here is the config from `/etc/network/interfaces` (I used the example 3 from here: https://wiki.debian.org/Bonding):

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto eth1 lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
        bond-slaves eth0 eth1 eth2
        bond-mode active-backup
        bond-primary eth0
        bond-miimon 100
        bond_downdelay 200
        bond_updelay 200

allow-bond0 eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

allow-bond0 eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

allow-bond0 eth2
iface eth2 inet manual

iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.4.127
        network 192.168.4.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.4.255
        gateway 192.168.4.1
```

I added eth1 as well for general testing.
This is the output from `ip r` before I unplug the cable from eth0:

```
default via 192.168.22.2 dev bond0
10.0.0.0/8 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 10.197.68.254
192.168.4.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.4.127
192.168.22.0/24 dev bond0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.22.31
```

And after I unplug the cables:

```
default via 192.168.22.2 dev bond0
10.0.0.0/8 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 10.197.68.254
192.168.4.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.4.127 linkdown
192.168.22.0/24 dev bond0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.22.31
```

As you can see, eth0 and the cellular interface eth2 receive different gateways via DHCP. So I can't set static GW for the cellular interface since it might change over time.

Why isn't this working properly? Or do you have a better idea how I could configure this?

Comment: bonding works mostly at Ethernet layer, so it can't be a solution for a multi-homed configuration.

Comment: I think this put me in the right direction. I can configure the route on the physical link eth0 and eth1 with `ip route` similar as described here: [link](https://kindlund.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/configuring-multiple-default-routes-in-linux/). But how can I fix a second route for the cellular interface if I don't know the GW?

Comment: At time of writing, documentation used is mainly valid for debian 11 (the actual stable version). LTS support just stopped for stretch. Is there any reasonable reason not to upgrade ?